# How to add email to an existing iOS app

Tags: ios, email, tabbar

I created an app based on the "Tabster" sample code from Apple.  The app runs great, but I want to add email to it. I created an email app. and have tried every approach I can think of, learn from a tutorial, or read, but it continually crashes. I posed the question on the Apple Dev. forum and several responses were to simply "copy the files over to the existing app. and you should be good."  Obviously its not this simple. I have added the MessageUI Framework and have tried copying the files in many different ways and Im am still stuck. Its Friday and this one problem has held me up since Monday.  I guess the first part is the fact that there are 2 main.m files and I have tried combining them, I have tried renaming the mail's main.m file to emailmain.m.  I dont know what else to try.

Its amazing to me that all of the documentation and all of the tutorials out there about creating email within an iOS app all start off with creating a new application. What am I missing?  How do I add email into a fully functioning app.  I would appreciate any guidance, links to literature, or tutorials on the subject.

Any help I can get on this will be tremendously appreciated.  There are several other types of things I would like to add on to it, but I cant even get email implemented into it!

Thank you for help you can provide.
John

Comment: You can't just copy the main.m over and expect it to work.  You need to copy the code from it.  The answer below will help but it sounds like you need to start with a very basic tutorial on using Objective-C and iOS SDK.

Answer (score 3):

This is the method I use all the time. It should be able to be added to ANY UIViewController simple and cleanly.

Import your framework:

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
```

Make sure you include your delegate in the interface:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

Then in your implementation add this method or a variation if you need it to be an IBAction or something like that:

```
- (void)sendEmail
{    
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        MFMailComposeViewController *email = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        email.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [email setSubject:@"My Email Subject"];

        [email setMessageBody:@"My message body." isHTML:NO];

        [self presentModalViewController:email animated:YES];

    } else {
        UIAlertView *emailAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email Failure" message:@"Your device is not configured to send email" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [emailAlert show];
    }
}
```

You can call this method on button click or anything you want. It will pull up an email composer view where your user can hit send.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the MessageUI Framework. Where ever you want to use it import it in the corresponding .h file and set up the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate.

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

Then when you want to send a message use the following code in the .m file:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

// Optional Configuration Parameters to make life easier for the user
[mailViewController setSubject:subjectString];
[mailViewController setMessageBody:messageString isHTML:YES];
[mailViewController setToRecipients:recipientsArray];

// Present the VIew Controller and clean up after ourselves
[self presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:YES];
[mailViewController release];
```

Add the appropriate delegate method, you can use it to dismiss the controller once the email is sent:

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here Is asample code to create email with an image as attachment .you can modify it according to your needs.

```
-(void)createEmail 
    {
    NSMutableString *emailBody = [[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"<html><body>"] retain];
       [emailBody appendString:@"<p>Some email body text can go here</p>"];
       UIImage *emailImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageName.png"];
       NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(emailImage)];

       NSString *base64String = [imageData base64EncodedString];
      [emailBody appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p><b><img src='data:image/png;base64,%@'></b></p>",base64String]];
      [emailBody appendString:@"</body></html>"];
        NSLog(@"%@",emailBody);

     //mail composer window
        MFMailComposeViewController *emailDialog = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        emailDialog.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [emailDialog setSubject:@"My Inline Image Document"];
        [emailDialog setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

        [self presentModalViewController:emailDialog animated:YES];
        [emailDialog release];
        [emailBody release];
    }
```